# RegEx match another pattern if first pattern fails

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Here's the logic I'm failing with:
`If the input is 14 characters, return characters 9 through 13. Otherwise, return everything.`

`(?<=^.{8}).{5}(?=.$)` works as I'd expect, passing with characters 9 through 13 as the result set. If I append `|.*` to the RegEx to make `(?<=^.{8}).{5}(?=.$)|.*`, it always returns everything. I'm obviously going about this incorrectly.

Any input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.{14}$).{8}(.*).$|^.*$
```

Try this .This will return characters from `9 to 13` when string is of 14 characters.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/29

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that Regex is a requirement, but since you are only dealing with string lengths, you can use substring as well

```
input.Length == 14 ? return input.Substring(8,5) : input;
```

Comment: Steve, thanks for putting this up as I'm sure some people will be doing this the hard way. You are correct that RegEx is a requirement in my case -- the application is finished and the RegEx is customizable on a per-customer basis. Thanks!